# Invalid collation "utf8_general_ci" in SQL Server SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, collation

I am trying to running the below query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    *, (Title COLLATE utf8_general_ci) 
FROM 
    BibTitles  
WHERE 
    TitlesID > '.$last_iterate_book_id.' 
ORDER BY 
    TitlesID ASC;
```

in PHP script. The above query is to get data from a SQL Server view.

When I am running the script, it is throwing the below error:

> Invalid collation 'utf8_general_ci'

I am using the collation because, my database contains data in different language and showing me those data as question mark (???) instead of actual data. I can't alter the database as well as table due to permission issue.

Please help me with this.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 doesn't support UTF-8 - you need to use some other collation

Comment: Is there any alternative for UTF-8 collation in sql server

Comment: SQL Server supports UCS-2 Unicode (2 byte per every character - roughly equivalent to UTF-16)